# how to populate an aspx bulletedList control with records from a database to show the bulletts

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a ASPX Bulletted list control

```
                <asp:BulletedList id="blProductsBulletedList" 
                BulletStyle="Disc"
                DataTextField="CheckListsFriendlyName"
                runat="server">                    
            </asp:BulletedList>
```

and i have a single column datatable bound to it in the page load:

```
            string strSQLQuery = "SELECT [CheckListsFriendlyName] FROM [SingleEnded2].[dbo].[WOCFriendlyNames]";
        // Run the query and bind the resulting DataSet
        // to the GridView control.
        DataTable dt = getCheckListExampleList(strSQLQuery);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            blProductsBulletedList.DataSource = dt;
            blProductsBulletedList.DataBind();
        }

        }
```

further down in the cs file is the 'getCheckListExampleList()':

```
        DataTable getCheckListExampleList(string strSQLQuery)
    {
        SqlConnection seConnection = new SqlConnection(Databases.getDbConnectionString("csSingleEnded2"));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand seCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLQuery, seConnection);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            seCmd.Connection = seConnection;
            sda.SelectCommand = seCmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            // The connection failed. Display an error message.
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the database", ex);
        }
        return dt;
      }
```

This works, however the list does not appear bulleted and just appears as if its just a view of the records. Can anyone point me in the right direction to show each result as a bulleted list item and also after X amount of results add titles to split the results up into sections?

Comment: What is the ***applied*** CSS of the generated HTML for the list? In other words, if you pull up the developer tools, what's the CSS that was ***applied*** to the HTML?

Comment: Where does your title come from for the sections?

Comment: just an inline style <ul id="MainContent_blProductsBulletedList" style="list-style-type: disc;"> i have added no other at this stage...